# How to select previous comment when check in 'pending changes' to Source Control in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, comments, reusability, checkin

When checking in my changeset in Visual Studio 2012, I want to reuse my previous comment(s) in the comment box as below snapshot. How can I get that?

[image]

Comment: Did you have this option before? We use TFS and VS2010/VS2012/VS2013 and I have never seen the option to select previous comments.
You can checkin via the vs studio cmd shell prompt and use a file as the comment:

tf checkin $/TFS/Path/To/Checkin/or/File /comment:@<comment file for reuse> /noprompt /recursive

Comment: I have never seen this before so I just ask